# Dynamic measure insider a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

So I have a few different KPI actual values (measure or average values). I want to display these in a disconnected table. But I want to keep the function to filter them by the slicer. All data is connected via relationship to the regions.
But the table being built is to collect a summary of each KPI with their name as an overview and is disconnected.

When I created this disconnected table, I realized that the slicer is not filtering the actual column, but the measures by them self are if I put them in a visual or another table.

How can I build this so the table is not static?
I've tried with filter direct on the calculate with SELECTEDVALUE measure and CONCATENATEX.

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

For the measure to be dynamic it needs to be created as a measure not as a calculation when you generate the table, so...

Create the table without the actual measures. Only with your KPI, Target, Score, Net Weight (i.e. all the values that are supposed to be static).

And then create a measure like this:

```
KPIMeasure = SWITCH(tbl[KPI]
  ,"Food Waste", ... //Food waste measure
  ,"Service Point Survey", ... //SPS measure
  ,"Service Request Feedback", ...
  ,"Total Recordable Accident Rate", ...
)
```